# unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 537 bytes

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this jQuery code to send data to PHP:

```
var fromdata2 = $('#form').serialize();
var file_data = $('#fileid').attr('files')[0];
var fromdata = new FormData();
fromdata.append('fileid', file_data);
fromdata.append('post_data', fromdata2);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fromdata,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "url",
    success: function (data)
    {
       alert("success");
    }
});
```

I receive the data in this form:

```
code=&amp;id=&amp;CTR_ID=&amp;ctr_name=asdsadsad&amp;air_name=Action+Airlines&amp;air_uniCode=XQ&amp;ctr_strDate=04%2F11%2F2017&amp;ctr_endDate=04%2F11%2F2017&amp;ctr_docNameHid=5337XXXXXXXXXX78_09-06-2016&amp;recstatus_val=1
```

But when I attempt to process it, with this code:

```
var_dump(unserialize($data));
```

I receive this error:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 537 bytes.
```

How can i unserialize it, to find the result in an array, like this:

```
array(
code=>,
id=>,
CTR_ID=>,
ctr_name=>'asdsadsad'
)
```

Comment: hi,  apokryfos 
plz send me right code for send AJAX request with form data and document upload file.

Comment: It's as simple as `$_GET['code']` and `$_FILES['']`

Comment: You're using the Javascript JQuery serialize function, and then trying to use the PHP unserialize function. Those are two different languages. They don't work in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @apokryfos in the comment, you can use `parse_str` to parse the query strings like below:

```
$queryString = "code=&id=&CTR_ID=&ctr_name=asdsadsad&air_name=Action+Airlines&air_uniCode=XQ&ctr_strDate=04%2F11%2F2017&ctr_endDate=04%2F11%2F2017&ctr_docNameHid=5337XXXXXXXXXX78_09-06-2016&recstatus_val=1";

parse_str($queryString, $queryArray);

print_r($queryArray);
```

To upload multiple files:

```
var ins = document.getElementById('fileid').files.length;
for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
    fromdata.append("fileid[]", document.getElementById('fileid').files[x]);
}
```

Comment: hi Manish Jangir
it working fine but i have faceing another problem in case i need to send multiple file then how can send it.??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send JSON data but you give it form url-encoded data, which are two different things. If you want to send JSON just do something like this:

```
var form_data = $("#form").serializeArray()
form_data.push({fileid: $('#fileid').attr('files')[0]});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fromdata,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "url",
    success: function (data)
    {
       alert("success");
    }
});
```

And then on PHP side just do `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'), true);`

Comment: files? You are having form data here. Add whatever you want with that `push` as shown above. jQuery's `serializeArray()` returns you an array of objects as key/value pair.